# Is this C++ method working as intended?

Tags: c++, string, methods, char, substr

Here's is my code in C++:

```
string searchValue(string& str, char tag)
{

    size_t pos1;
    size_t pos2;

    pos1=str.find(tag);
    pos2=str.find(tag,pos1+1);
    string result=(str.substr( pos1+1 ,(pos2-(pos1+1)) ));

    str=str.substr(pos2+1);

    return result;
}
```

The purpose is to put in as arguements a string (example=`< feature token = "do" id = "98" freq = "1" />`) and a char (`tag='\"'` for this one).

I intend for this method to return the string contained between 2 occurrences of the *tag* argument along with removing the part of the string *str* up to(and including) the position of that 2nd occurrence of *tag*.

That being my goal I would expect the commands:

```
string s="< feature token = \"do\" id = \"98\" freq = \"1\" />";
cout<<searchValue(s,'\"')<<endl<<searchValue(s,'\"')<<endl<<searchValue(s,'\"')<<endl;
```

to display

```
do
98
1
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: We have plenty of documentation for formatting. Being new isn't an excuse not to read it.

Comment: Well, does it do what you expect?

Comment: You only seem to tell us what you expect of the code, not what you're actually getting.

Comment: Have you tried compiling it yet ?

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal While I agree with the spirit of your message, lets do a better job welcoming new members. We don't want to become like the comp.lang.c++ usenet group.

Answer (score 3):

What you're doing wrong is assuming that that functions in a << expression evaluate in left-to-right order.  They don't necessarily.  And in this case your compiler is evaluating them right to left.

(To clarify, since the original question didn't say, the behavior he's seeing is that it's printing out:

```
1
98
do
```

instead.  (Or at least, that's what I assume because that's what I get when I compile it with g++)

What's happening is that the expressions on either side of an operator both have to be run before the operator, but they can be run in either order.  For whatever reason, in this case, your compiler is running the rightmost call to searchValue first and then the middle one and then the left one.  Since searchValue changes s, this, of course, changes the answer.

You might think that the code you wrote is guaranteed to give you the same answer as:

```
  string s="< feature token = \"do\" id = \"98\" freq = \"1\" />";
  string x = searchValue(s,'\"');
  string y = searchValue(s,'\"');
  string z = searchValue(s,'\"');
  cout << x << endl << y << endl << z << endl;
```

but it isn't, and, at least in this particular case, it doesn't.  If you run that code, you'll see that it gives you the expected result.  Your code is running as if it were written like this:

```
  string s="< feature token = \"do\" id = \"98\" freq = \"1\" />";
  string z = searchValue(s,'\"');
  string y = searchValue(s,'\"');
  string x = searchValue(s,'\"');
  cout << x << endl << y << endl << z << endl;
```

Comment: "Because the left-shift operator groups left-to-right, the left subexpression is evaluated first and then the right one." --describing an example, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yck2zaey%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Comment: That's quite likely the case in Microsoft's C++ compiler, but the C++ standard doesn't say that inputs to operators must be evaluated in any particular order.  It's up to the compiler, and there's not even a requirement that the compiler be consistent.  It can do it different ways at different times when it feels like it.  And that's clearly what's happening when this code is run in g++.

Comment: @John: In general, functions with side-effects are a PITA to use. A search function has no business modifying the input. - In this case, if you want to protect yourself from these issues, you'd have to make the return type of search `void`, so it couldn't be used in larger expressions, and return the result through an out parameter.